# What's the best way to create an API Wrapper?

Tags: python, json

I have six different APIs in Python that all have functionally equivalent methods, but differently named and they each have their respective functionality on each site. I want to avoid rewriting the same code 6 times, and create a wrapper for all six that would have uniform functions which each respective file would understand as calling their "own" function. AKA, if I have `getData1()` on one, `getData2()` on another, and so on, and I want to make a function `getData()` that can be called once with each respective Python library so that I don't have to write the same logic multiple times.

What's the most effective way to do this? Would this actually save time or be more complex than individually coding each API's logic that I need (I will be writing some pretty lengthy logic)?

Would the process be to write the library and just make each function call in the wrapper call the function in the file, or would I have to rewrite all names to be the same (also, some have different parameters, but they are functionally equivalent for what I want to do)

Thanks, I have never done something like this before (just started learning how to interact with APIs in Python, actually)

Comment: Just for clarity - am I right in thinking that you have 6 API classes, each with functionally equivalent methods, but with different names (i.e in API 1 it's called `getData1()` while in API 2 it's `getData2()` etc? And you want some kind of wrapper which will map `getData` to the appropriate method, depending on which API is in use?

Comment: @match Exactly. Sorry if that wasn't too clear. To further clarify, `getData()` should match the appropriate method in respective API classes, and call it.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I can think of is to first of all build a mapping of generic name to API-specific name. Next define a 'wrapping' class, which takes an api and any potential api arguments, and then iterates over the mapping, instantiating the api class (with appropriate attributes), then creates the 'alias' attributes, pointing to the original ones:

```
class API1():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def getData1(self):
        return "Getting " + self.url

    def postData1(self):
        return "Posting " + self.url

class API2():
    def __init__(self, url, username):
        self.url = url

    def getData2(self):
        return "Getting " + self.url + " for " self.username

class wrapped_api():
    mapping = {
    "getData": {
        "API1": "getData1",
        "API2": "getData2",
    },
    "postData": {
        "API1": "postData1",
    }
}
    def __init__(self, api, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = api(*args, **kwargs)
        for key, val in self.mapping.items():
            if api.__name__ in val:
                setattr(self, key, getattr(instance, val[api.__name__]))

api1 = wrapped_api(API1, "http://api1.example.com")
api2 = wrapped_api(API2, "http://api2.example.com", "alice")
print(api1.getData()
print(api1.postData())
print(api2.getData())
```

This uses `getattr` and `setattr` to do the heavy lifting, and `*args/**kwargs` to ensure that all arguments are passed through to the original class.

Note that the mappings can include or omit a particular API method when mapping (e.g. `API2` has no `postData` method).

Let me know if there's any parts which either don't quite fit what you're trying to achieve, or you don't understand.

Comment: Did you mean to call API2?  api2 = wrapped_api(API2, "http://api2.example.com", "alice")